# 12V 1A over CAT5 ethernet cable about 12 metres long

Tags: power-electronics

I'm setting up a CCTV system and already happen to have an ethernet cable in place. I intend to send the video signal through the ethernet cable to another room where my DVR is positioned and I have an UPS. It would be nice if I didn't have to buy another UPS for the camera and could use the ethernet cable to transfer power from where I have my DVR and UPS as well as send the video signal through it.

Has anyone ever risked 12v 1A through a CAT5 ethernet cable? Would a real engineer say this is definately a no go? (I'm not a real engineer, just a DIY layman.)

I'm assuming that the ethernet cable is only good for 5V 1A max. Not 12v 1A.

What are the professionals opinions?

Thankyou very much - Si

Comment: You probably want to use PoE. Class 3 or 4 seem to be suitable. https://www.a1securitycameras.com/technical-support/pover-over-ethernet-classes-comparison-chart/

Comment: Class 0 shud be adequate

Comment: Power over ethernet runs at over 40v, so there is no 5v limit.

Comment: If 12W is fine, I don't know for sure what type of cable I've got installed, we installed the cables 20 years ago. 'Adequate' sounds ok and no risk - Thanks this will save me £60 on a second UPS - Si

Comment: You will want to know the exact type of the cable, to find the cable manual, so you can read the ratings of the cable. We also do not know the length of your cable. Without knowing cable ratings, AWG, and length, we don't know how much voltage will drop in the cable and we also cannot know how much voltage drop your camera can tolerate. There is just too many variables to say if it works or not.

Comment: POE is not obvious in your setup. Are your cameras supporting it? Or you are planning to "split" the power off the cable?

Comment: Wire voltage is rated by its insulation rating. Using a simple voltage drop calculator this is what I got. Voltage drop: 4.67
Voltage drop percentage: 38.94%
Voltage at the end: 7.33  I used 36 feet wire 1 pair 28 AWG copper for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm assuming that the ethernet cable is only good for 5V 1A max. Not 12v 1A.

Voltage rating is about insulation, and 12V is fine.

Current rating is about voltage drop due to wire resistance, and fire hazard if the wire heats too much.

First thing you should do is grab a multimeter and measure how much current your camera actually uses. I bet it's going to be a lot less than 1A. If that's the case, it will probably work fine. It will also probably work fine with a lot less than 12V, so who cares about voltage drop. If it's a modern camera there's probably a switching regulator and everything inside runs on 3V3 or 5V. I've run some CCTV bullet cams on 6xAA batteries.

You don't say if it's an ethernet camera or if it's a composite video camera.

Ethernet camera: don't connect your 12V powered ethernet wires to the RJ45 jack on the camera or it will die.

Composite video camera: you'll probably need an impedance matching / balun to connect the 75R coax to the twisted pair.

Now the important thing is you should absolutely add a fuse on the power supply side, especially if the power supply can deliver enough current to overheat and fry the tiny CAT5 wires in case of a short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The current is the only rating you need to be careful with in your situation. POE is typically 48V but is below 1A per pair. Type 4 pushes the current to 960 mA per pair so you should be able to use two pairs to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Most ethernet cable is either 24 or 26 AWG.  Assuming you're going to use a pair for supply and a pair for return, that puts the combined cross-sectional area at something like 21 and 23 AWG per pair, respectively.  Applying the 700 circular mils/amp rule gives the OK to 24 AWG but not 26.  However, that's a very conservative rule of thumb and there are some allowances that could be made for having the current split into two wires.  You should also verify if the voltage drop is going to be a problem.  For a 12m out and back run, you should see around a volt drop for 24 AWG and 1.6V for 26 AWG.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power-over-Ethernet (PoE) to power your devices. PoE supports up to 14W of power for a Type 1, and even more for Type 2 or Type 3.

More here: https://www.perle.com/supportfiles/poe_background_technical_note.shtml

Each end of the Ethernet cable will need hardware: a 'power injector' at the host, and 'power extractor' at the device. All this can be powered by your UPS at the host.

All this is assuming you're using IP cameras, which if your infrastructure is Ethernet cabling would be your best choice.